# Deleting all array values that are non-numeric

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have an array I want to clean that has entries like:

```
arr = (['1140.0', '-600.0', '-700.6', '5700.45', '(~par)', '(-6.0', '690.6', ....., 
'-----', '5750.65', '#', '-850.0'])
```

I want to clean this array of all `non-numeric` values and keeps order in the array to get an output like this:

```
arr_clean = (['1140.0', '-600.0', '-700.6', '5700.45', '690.6', '5750.65', '-850.0'])
```

Some values are negative so I can't simply see if the first character of the element is non-numeric and some values have numbers in them but need to be taken out as well - like the value `(-6.0`.

I first converted to a dataframe to see if I could just change `pd.to_numeric(df[col])` and clean it that way but it doesn't feel efficient to switch back and forth from array to df and back again (the size of the array is ~**800,000** and I want my final output to be an array).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: By `array` do you mean a Python list?  If so, why the `()`?  Or is this a numpy `ndarray`?  If so, what's the shape and dtype?

Answer (score 0):

Doing `float('(-6.0')` will throw an exception when it is not a number. It is perfectly pythonic ([duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)) to use this feature:

```
arr = (['1140.0', '-600.0', '-700.6', '5700.45', '(~par)', '(-6.0', '690.6', '...',
'-----', '5750.65', '#', '-850.0'])

arr_clean = list()

for elm in arr:
    try:
        float(elm)
        print("could     convert string to float:", elm)
        arr_clean.append(elm)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

print(arr_clean)
```

This outputs:

```
could     convert string to float: 1140.0
could     convert string to float: -600.0
could     convert string to float: -700.6
could     convert string to float: 5700.45
could not convert string to float: '(~par)'
could not convert string to float: '(-6.0'
could     convert string to float: 690.6
could not convert string to float: '...'
could not convert string to float: '-----'
could     convert string to float: 5750.65
could not convert string to float: '#'
could     convert string to float: -850.0
['1140.0', '-600.0', '-700.6', '5700.45', '690.6', '5750.65', '-850.0']
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way than to iterate over all elements?

Just by the size of my actual array (around 800,000 elements) it may take too much computational power.

Comment: Any filtering will take at least `O(n)`, unless you parallelize the task, or push it down to lower level code. To be honest, I'd expect setting up the parallelization would take longer then just doing it... Also, I just tested  on 800 000 with 50/50 strings vs numbers, and it took 670ms to run. Is that too slow for your use case? Hmm, when you run it, did you keep the print statements? Make sure you remove them, if you don't it will take WAY longer. Use the keyword `pass` instead of `print(e)` in the last line, and just remove the other one.

Answer (score 0):

If I can assume your `array` is in a dataframe, you can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors=coerce` and then [`Dataframe.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
# Example dataframe which was provided
data = {'Array':['1140.0', '-600.0', '-700.6', '5700.45', '(~par)', '(-6.0', '690.6', '.....', '-----', '5750.65', '#', '-850.0']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
      Array
0    1140.0
1    -600.0
2    -700.6
3   5700.45
4    (~par)
5     (-6.0
6     690.6
7     .....
8     -----
9   5750.65
10        #
11   -850.0
```

Apply `pd.to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Array, errors='coerce').dropna()

0     1140.00
1     -600.00
2     -700.60
3     5700.45
6      690.60
9     5750.65
11    -850.00
Name: Array, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I just bench marked this against my solution, and it takes 445ms, 33% faster than my 670ms, (but with longer setup).